# Modifying Animator Controller parameters

Tags: unity, animation, animation-controller

I have this GameObject with an AnimatorController. The AnimatorController has several states in which I want to parametrize the animation's speed because configuration. For this, I've created an animation parameter, called "RotationMultiplier" and set up the "Speed/Multiplier" value to this paramter on the needed states.

Now, my idea is being able to configure this speed from a script "somewhere." I've read a bit about StateMachineBehaviours, but my initial idea was executing this once, instead of once in each frame/state.

The "OnStateMachineEnter" function does not execute at all, and with the OnEnable I don't have access to the Animator (nor the parameters).

So, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If this is just an initial configuration, you can set it from the `Start()` method of an ordinary `MonoBehaviour` attached to the `GameObject` you're configuring.

Here's an example that lets you define the parameters in data, and tune them live in the Inspector while the game is playing.

```
public class AnimationConfiguration : MonoBehaviour {

    [System.Serializable]
    public struct FloatParameter {
         public string name;
         public float value;
    }

    public FloatParameter[] floatParameters;

    void Start() {
        var animator = GetComponent<Animator>();

        foreach(var parameter in floatParameters)
            animator.SetFloat(parameter.name, parameter.value);
    }

    // Allow live editing in the Inspector during play mode.
    void OnValidate() {
        if(Application.isPlaying)
            Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: There isn't any way to configure this without relaying on an attached GameObject? My idea was to have all this "starter values" somewhere else due code organization and such.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your application then. If you want one initial value that affects every object using this Controller, then you can just write the values you want directly into the controller. You only need a script if you want to override that initial value for specific objects / runtime

Comment: Yeah, my (asbtract) idea was to have a single file for some parameters (both on animations and other stuff) I wanted to change easily from my code (or a file on application load), so I could avoid both manually changing the controller parameter value and going through all the GameObjects to initialize the same value.